# Should I seek the migration of a page despite it not being off-topic AND against the OP wishes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

Long story short, I'm trying to grow the permanent-Beta community where I am a moderator.  One of the things that I regularly do is ask Stack Overflow (SO) users to post their Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange(JSE).  In some cases, I assist them in the migration process if they state that they are happy to migrate (often they agree and admit that they didn't even know JSE existed).

Last month a new user asked [a question regarding .htaccess/redirecting for their Joomla project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64789556/2943403).  This question is 100% valid on SO -- no debate about it.  However, Joomla has its own functionality which also enables redirecting.

In case any comments under the question might be removed, I'll add an image to preserve the dialogue:

> [image]

In addition to the aforementioned factors these are the things that I am considering:

1. Joomla SMEs will be more likely to find and contribute Joomla-specific insights on JSE (where they volunteer).
2. JSE will benefit from receiving more questions/activity/users from the migration.
3. SO won't even notice the loss of this single .htaccess page.
4. I am not acting selfishly on a personal level, but I am trying to actively support the community that I moderate.
5. New users don't often understand the curation and community management decisions that veteran users are working for.
6. There is no reason for me to be pushy about this single page -- it is not going to lead to the apocalypse.

**I would like to hear answers which argue for/against migrating the page to JSE and give specific reasons for this stance. If some reasons for your decision bear more weight than others, please clarify this. Also, if you think I should have "played my cards" differently, I'm willing to hear that too.**

<sub>For the record, I have no idea why the OP is so dead set against the migration; no justification was expressed in the comments.</sub>

Comment: We don’t migrate content if it is on topic here. So no, don’t seek migration.

Comment: Just because something is *more* ontopic for one site doesn't make it off topic for another. If it's on topic for [main] it's on topic for it. At best, let them know there is a community for Joomla in the comments, and perhaps the OP will use it in the future. That is the best you can hope for.

Comment: And you can lead a horse to water, but you can’t make it drink.

Comment: I am aware of these things.  However, I have successfully had Joomla questions migrated to JSE several times this year -- typically after the OP agrees to the migration. My question is asking for arguments from both sides of the debate.

Comment: Just because one user was happy to, doesn't mean another will be. Every user is different. Perhaps, if they don't get the answer they want they'll ask on the other community, but if you know the answer, then I feel you should still be trying to answer it on [main]; don't "ignore" the chance to help them if you can just because it's on [main] and not [Joomla.se].

Comment: The OP already received a satisfactory answer -- they will in NO WAY at a loss by the migration.

Comment: @Larnu Do you feel my question is not `usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched`?  I am not taking a side as much as I am asking for opinions on both sides.  How much more care do I need to take when crafting a question to avoid these downvotes?

Comment: @mickmackusa “typically after the OP agrees” is the differentiator there. See my answer, which is what moderators generally use when judging a migration request.

Comment: That is not what votes are about on meta, @mickmackusa... Fromthe link I gave you: *"Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."*

Comment: @mickmackusa Just a side note out of curiosity: Don't we have a SE network site for CMSs in general? Well, I know that there's a specific one for WordPress. Would it be useful to have a more general SE site for Content Management specific concerns and techniques? Or what is Joomla focussed on? The special Joomla PHP ("multi")universe?

Comment: @Larnu I just copied that text from the link you sent me to.  I am not new to Stack Exchange.  Not all Metas behave like this one.  If I made a stance one way or another, I would understand the upvotes would be in support of my stance and downvotes would be against my stance -- but I am not taking a stance.  I am asking for stances.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Cody will agree with you that all CMSs should be piled into one CMS Stack Exchange community.

Comment: Your stance, however, is "this should be migrated" @mickmackusa, and clearly those that vote down are saying "This should not be migrated". That is how votes on meta work... I'm not going to engage any more with the tone you are implying in your message though... It feels you are too emotionally involved, and that is skewing your opinion.

Comment: @mickmackusa I just checked, there's also Sitecore and Craft CMS. I am pretty sure that besides the system / framework specific topics (which could be handled by tags like programming language tags here), all those CMS systems should share a bigger part of commonalities, because they are designed to cover the same requirements more or less, no?

Comment: We have sites for Wordpress, Drupal, Magento and now Joomla? The PHP CMS maturity cycle seems to include "having your own SE site". would bet that a fair percentage of questions on those sites are dupes of broader questions asked over here. Seems like a waste, IMO.

Comment: @yivi Ah, I wasn't sure if Magento and Drupal also fall in the CMS category. That's a mess, yes. (Lizard lovers SE :-P)

Comment: Just my two cents worth but that quoted comment chain seems more antagonistic/argumentative than appearing to be helpful

Comment: @charlie which parts feel antagonistic to you?

Comment: @yivi I am sure the the folks that pushed from JSE did so so that Joomla "had the same thing" that WP had.  Little brother syndrome.  As stated here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351032/352329  SO has 3x as many Joomla questions as JSE.

Comment: @charlietfl Well, I agree that this side discussion is off-topic, but I think we have discovered a point, which is possibly worth a separate discussion at MSE. But I see nothing  _"antagonistic"_ or _"unconstructive"_ in these comments. If we'll end up with a common SE CMS site, which all betas will be merged in, what would be destroyed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was referring to comments in the original SO question, the ones shown in the image in this question

Comment: As for OP not wanting to migrate, it appears they got an answer in less than 10 minutes. Hard to beat that kind of service

Comment: @Char yes, AND the migration will in no way damage that good service.  I even invited anubhava to come to JSE and share his wisdom.  The JSE community (David) will never grow if it has to fight SO (Goliath) for eyeballs.

Comment: As a 33 rep user I would be pretty irritated by the comment conversation on the question.  Most new users do a good job just asking properly on [so], before even considering the kraken that is StackExchange and Meta. Especially the last comment comes across as borderline confrontational, asking repeatedly for justification and loading it with the commenter's chagrin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [central FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) is unambiguous about this:

> - **Don't migrate for the sake of migration.**
>
>   We only migrate questions because they are *not a good fit on the
>   original site*. It is perfectly possible for a question to be good fits
>   on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere,
>   unless the OP specifically requests it. As a general rule, if someone
>   asks a question *here*, and it's a good fit *here*, it should stay *here*.

If the OP opposes migration then the post doesn’t even qualify for the exception in that statement: *unless the OP specifically requests it*.

The post should not be migrated.

Note that the FAQ post I linked to codifies how moderators should handle migration requests; we’d deny migration.

Comment: So my mission/goal becomes: "convince the OP that the migration would be a good thing"?

Comment: @mickmackusa I’d just _let it go_. The post is now a month old, the OP will not thank you for reopening the discussion again. If you feel the JSE community can benefit from the question subject being posted there, create a new question yourself on JSE (write one yourself, don’t copy).

Comment: I don't think I can get behind contributing to redundant content in the network.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yet you argue that there are loads of .htaccess posts on SO already. If the post is a better fit on JSE then presumably that’s because the **answers** would be unique to JSE.

Comment: I don't know if I follow your arguement.  I was very clear a month ago and today, in the fact that the question and its answer are perfectly valid in either community.  My point is that the question is specifically in the scope of Joomla because it is a Joomla website AND Joomla has a specific redirecting feature (which I am not qualified to explain because I don't have any experience with that feature).  I know that there is an alternative way to redirect within Joomla and the folks that can give this insight might only find it on JSE.